# Chamar aplicação Java via PHP

Tags: php, java, jsf

Eu criei uma aplicação em Java aqui na minha empresa porém eles querem chamar essa aplicação em Java via um site feito em PHP. Gostaria de saber se é possível eu fazer um código PHP que chame uma aplicação Java, não importa a forma se for por link por botão ou qualquer outra forma.

Até o momento o que precisa ser feito e chamar a minha aplicação Java via PHP e gostaria de saber se isso é possível de fazer e como isso pode ser feito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [exec()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) para chamar um programa Java ou qualquer outro programa que esteja no seu servidor.

Mas **cuidado**, essa função pode ser **perigosa** se deixar o usuário executar qualquer comando, por exemplo, ele pode chamar uma função que corrompa seus arquivos ou até formate a máquina.

Chamar um programa em Java pode ser feito assim:

```
<?php exec("java -jar arquivo.jar argumentos", $saida); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer uso da função [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) do PHP para executar o teu Java:

Ficheiro `testar.java`

```java
class testar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Olá mundo!");
    }
}
```

Ficheiro `testar.php`

```php
echo exec('java testar');
```

Correr o ficheiro `testar.php`

```sh
$ php testar.php
Olá mundo!
```

**Nota:**
Tens que tem em atenção o caminho para o ficheiro Java, de resto não deverás ter problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de consumir uma aplicação Java a partir do PHP é usando o [Zend Java Bridge](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/java_bridge_component.htm). Ele permite que você consuma suas classes criadas em Java a partir do seu script PHP.

Segue o fluxo que é executado para executar esse código Java<sup>en</sup>.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um exemplo de código utilizando esse recurso seria:

```
<?php

// cria o objeto Java
$stock = new Java("com.ticker.JavaStock");

// consome os métodos em Java
$news = $stock->get_news($_GET['ticker']);

// Exibe os resultados
foreach($news as $news_item) {
    print "$news_item<br>\n";
}
```

Vale lembrar que esse recurso está disponível somente na versão Entreprise do Zend Server, que **não é barata**.

Talvez reescrever essa aplicação Java em PHP ou porta-la para uma interface web faça mais sentido.

Comment: hmm bacana amigo porem fazer a minha aplicação java em php esta fora de cogitacao ate entao pois e java web e assim a minha aplicacao consiste em pegar o macaddress da maquina de quem acessa para poder efetuar uma cadastramento e em php nao e possivel fazer esse tipo de coisa ate onde eu conheço e claro

Comment: Então você precisa da aplicação Java rodando do client, executar ela a partir do servidor vai obter somente o mac do servidor, não do client.

Comment: Talvez essa pergunta possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php